# Select and scale variables in shiny app dynamically

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I have a shiny app where I want the user to be able to select which variables to keep in the final data frame and then also select which variables to scale into a percent. I have this working, but I am running into a little puzzle. The problem is if the user decides they want to add an additional variable (or remove one), they have to redo the scaling. This could be a problem if my users have many columns they are working on. How can I keep the scaling work the user has already done, while allowing for the addition or removal of variables from the final data frame?

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("select_var", label = "Select Variables"),
  selectInput("scalescore", label = NULL, choices = c("")),
  actionButton("scale", "Scale Scores"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")

)

# Define server 
server <- function(session, input, output) {
  # define the reactive values
  values <- reactiveValues(df_final = NULL)

  # dynamically generate the variable names
  observe({
    vchoices <- names(mtcars)
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "select_var", choices = vchoices)
  })

  # dynamically generate the variables to scale
  observe({
    vchoices <- names(values$df_final)
    updateSelectInput(session, "scalescore", choices = vchoices)
  })

  # select the variables based on checkbox
  observe({
    req(input$select_var)
    df_sel <- mtcars %>% select(input$select_var) 
    values$df_final <- df_sel
  })

  observeEvent(input$scale, {
    name <- rlang::sym(paste0(input$scalescore, "_scaled"))
    values$df_final <- values$df_final %>% mutate(!!name := round(!!rlang::sym(input$scalescore)/max(!!rlang::sym(input$scalescore), na.rm = TRUE)*100, 1))})

 output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(values$df_final)
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will need to maintain a vector which tracks whether a variable was scaled or not. Here is how it's done,

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

# Define UI 
ui <- fluidPage(
  checkboxGroupInput("select_var", label = "Select Variables"),
  selectInput("scalescore", label = NULL, choices = c("")),
  actionButton("scale", "Scale Scores"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("table")

)

server = function(input,output,session){
  #Column names are static
  names = colnames(mtcars)

  # data scructure to store if the variable is scaled
  is_scaled = logical(length(names))
  names(is_scaled) = names #Set the names of the logical vector to the column names 

  #Update the checkbox with the column names of the dataframe
  observe({
    updateCheckboxGroupInput(session, "select_var", choices = names)
  })

  # Update the list of choices but dont include the scaled vaiables
  observe({
    vchoices <- names(data())
    vchoices = vchoices[vchoices %in% names]
    updateSelectInput(session, "scalescore", choices = vchoices)
  })

  #When the scle button is pressed, the vector which contains the list of scaled variables is updated 
  observeEvent(input$scale,{
    if(is_scaled[[input$scalescore]]){
      is_scaled[[input$scalescore]] <<- FALSE
    }else{
      is_scaled[[input$scalescore]] <<- TRUE
    }
  })

  #Function to scale the variables
  scale = function(x){
    return(round(x/max(x,na.rm = T)*100,1))
  }

  data = reactive({
    req(input$select_var)
    input$scale #simply to induce reactivity

    #Select the respective columns
    df = mtcars%>%
      select(input$select_var)

    if(any(is_scaled[input$select_var])){
      temp_vec = is_scaled[input$select_var] #Get a list of variables selected
      true_vec = temp_vec[which(temp_vec)] #Check which ones are scaled
      true_vec_names = names(true_vec) #Get the names of the variables scales

      #Scale the variables respectively
      df = df%>%
        mutate_at(.vars = true_vec_names,.funs = funs(scaled = scale(.)))
    }

    return(df)
  })

  output$table = DT::renderDataTable(data())
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

`is_scaled` tracks whether a particular column is scaled or not. When it is later selected, it is scaled if the value is `TRUE` in this vector.

Additional functionality is also added where if the scale button is pressed twice the scale column is removed.

Comment: Thank you for this creative solution! I am trying to figure out where the variables are renamed with the `_scaled`, does `mutate_at()` add that? Also, when multiple variables are selected but only one is scaled, the scaled column is called simply `scaled` making it difficult to know which variables it belongs to.

Comment: Yep, you can work with the mutate_at function to fix this

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't figure out how to do this within `mutate_at` but I got it working with an if statement that checks for the variable name `scaled` and then renames it:     `if("scaled" %in% colnames(df)){
      df <- df %>% rename(!!paste0(true_vec_names, "_scaled") := scaled)
    }`